# Error in setting up ionic project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am unable to create an Ionic project. I get an error when i run npm install command. I am new to Ionic project so kindly guide me if i am wrong.

The problem is this, if I create a blank ionic project:

ionic start myProjectName1 blank --type ionic1

It will successfully download (app base, starter template and resources)

```
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-base/archive/master.tar.gz
 https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-starter-blank/archive/master.tar.gz
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-default-resources/archive/master.tar.gz
```

Then the npm install kicks off. It attempts to download a sass binary that doesn’t exist (404 error):

```
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node
```

I have checked from

```
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download
```

and version 3.13.1 does not exist

Comment: If so, this should be reported to the ionic team, open an [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues) there.

Comment: I am having almost the same issue as you. I wonder what happened, I was able to create new projects without any issues but now it just doesn't work.